# Delete every second item in the list Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket

My program works with all lists except the improper lists (which have an atom in the `cdr` field of the last *cons* cell). Please help upgrade this program to work with the improper lists:

```
(define (ndelete lst) 
    (let recur ((i 1) (rest lst))
        (cond ((null? rest) '())
              ((= i 2) (recur 1 (cdr rest)))
              (else (cons (car rest) (recur (+ i 1) (cdr rest)))))))
```

Comment: Please explain how it doesn't work with improper lists. Do you get unexpected results, or an error message, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to fix your base condition, `(null? rest)`. If you want to support improper lists, you should check for `(not (pair? rest))` instead.

Of course, this has an annoying side-effect of making your function handle any object - not just lists. For any non-list object, it just returns nil. If that's a problem for you, you'll need to encapsulate your recursive function and make sure `lst` is in fact a list. Like so:

```
(define (ndelete lst) 
      (letrec ((recur (lambda (i rest)
                        (cond ((not (pair? rest)) '())
                          ((= i 2) (recur 1 (cdr rest)))
                          (else (cons (car rest) (recur (+ i 1) (cdr rest))))))))
        (if (pair? lst) 
            (recur 1 lst) 
            (raise (condition (make-error) 
                     (make-message-condition `(,lst is not a pair)))))))
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark the answer as accepted so it will be removed from the unanswered questions list. If you found a different solution, please post it as an answer and mark that as accepted. Cheers.